# After first download with youtube-dl my access to youtube was blocked

Tags: youtube, playlist, youtube-dl

I used youtube-dl to download a video and use VPN to access youtube.
After connect to the VPN my ip was changed and I can see youtube.com.
But after try to download first video I can not download any thing and the log is:

```
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is
unreachable> (caused by URLError(OSError(101, 'Network is unreachable'),))
```

So I looking for solution for this error and just find somthing like this link:

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/9438

And after I read it, I can not find any solution for my case.

I try to curl address also but this try is faild and it shown me this error:
* Could not resolve host: www.youtube.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.youtube.com

```
youtube-dl --version
2018.03.14

curl --version
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1a zlib/1.2.11
```

And wonderful thing is I can see youtube.com in my firefox browser but I can not access to it with `curl` or `youtube-dl`.

It seems somthing crashed after about 5 minutes and I can not access to youtube website.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot, I realized that the problem was from `CURL` and `VPN` so I deleted the 'curl'.
And 'youtube-dl' completely removed and reinstalled.
And then it works for me.

Comment: I discovered that disconnecting, then reconnecting to my VPN resolved this issue. Also noted that my connection to the VPN had been idle for several hours.